# Background colour on hover not working properly in safari with Tailwind

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have labels of checkboxes styled like this

```
<label class="border select-none rounded-md shadow font-semibold text-gray-600 px-4 py-2 hover:cursor-pointer hover:bg-theme_one-500 hover:text-white transition-all duration-300 ease-in-out">
    <input...>
</label>
```

Those looks like this when hovered,
[image]

As you can see it's kind of cropped from top and left. Only happens on Safari. No problem on Chrome and Firefox. If I remove shadow class from labels everything works fine, but that's not very convenient.

How can I solve this?

**Solved: Adding *overflow-auto* class fixed the problem**